# SQLitePCL Select call - ISQLiteStatement.Step retrieval condition

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite, uwp

I'm making an UWP app with SQLitePCL

I have a table called "Song"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Song
                (ID INTEGER Primary Key AutoIncrement NOT NULL
                , Artist VARCHAR(200)
                , Title VARCHAR(200)
                , Album VARCHAR(200)
                , Path VARCHAR(255)
                , Type VARCHAR(50));
```

And a retrieval function:

```
private static async Task<Song> getSong(int sID)
    {
        //TODO IMPLIMENT TYPE CHECK
        Song newsong = null;
        using (var statement = dbConnection.Prepare(@"SELECT [ID],[Path] FROM Song WHERE ID = ?"))
        {
            statement.Bind(1, sID);
            if(SQLiteResult.DONE == statement.Step())
            {
                string path = (string)statement[1];
                StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
                StorageFile songfile = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
                MusicProperties prop = await songfile.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
                newsong = new Song()
                {
                    Id = (int)statement[0],
                    SongFile = songfile,
                    Artist = prop.Artist,
                    Album = prop.Album,
                    Title = prop.Title
                };

            }
        }
        return newsong;
    }
```

The problem however, is that is seems to ignore the condition I've set:

```
if(SQLiteResult.DONE == statement.Step()
```

Is it the wrong kind of condition? I simply want to retrieve the values once a row with a matching ID is encountered.

Comment: What value does `Step` actually return?

Comment: Note also that SQLite ignores all those `varchar` sizes - [everything is just `text`](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result code `SQLiteResult.DONE` means `sqlite3_step()` has finished executing. In your code snippet, if your data table still have rows need to read, `statement.Step()` will return `SQLiteResult.ROW` result code, which means `sqlite3_step()` has another row ready to read, not finished.

So the condition should be

```
while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
```

More details about the result codes please reference [this article](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html).